# Java Keylistener without window being open?

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm trying to create an auto-clicker in Java(only language I know and I just learned Threads). I want to have the applet open in it's own window(not on a webpage), and I want to be able to start and stop the program with the spacebar without the window being selected so that I can use the auto-clicker on another program and be able to stop it without alt-f4ing a bunch of stuff.

Is there anything you can refer me to that can help me along with this? Or do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be out of the scope of a Java applet. In fact, global keyboard hooks are definitely out of the scope of simply using Java, but I can help you get moving in the right direction.

However, you have some hope. I'll point you into the direction of [JNI (Java Native Interface)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/), which will allow you to use native libraries. Now, since you want to stay in the Java world, I suggest not directly using JNI because you'll have to write some confusing native code (typically C, C++). There are several wrappers for JNI that allow you to use the functions but the native implementations are abstracted away, but a lot of these cost money.

---

So the best solution for you, I think, is [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/twall/jna/). This allows you to directly call native libraries from within Java. (NOTE: The implementation not will be cross platform. You have to make separate implementations for Windows, Linux, etc.) There's a good example for Windows keyboard hooks in the examples on the project website.

As for opening it's own window not in a webpage, do you want the applet to not run within the browser but in its own separate process, or just be in a separate window and still rely on the browser window being open?

- If you want to simply launch a new window and still require the browser to be open, then here's a good example:

  ```
  final Frame window = new Frame("This is the Frame's Title Bar!");
  window.add(new Label("This is the Frame."));
  window.setSize(300,200);
  window.setVisible(true);

  window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
          window.dispose();
      }
  });
  ```
- If you want the applet to spawn a new process and run without the need of the browser, look into [JavaFX](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/).

Comment: In it's own separate window would probably be best.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer but hopefully helpful :)

You can using JNA, it's a cakewalk!!

1. get JNA (jna.jar)
2. create your own mapping for User32 (User32.dll) in the form

   ```
   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("User32", User32.class,   Options.UNICODE_OPTIONS);


   // dwWakeMask Constants
   public static final int QS_ALLEVENTS = 0x04BF;
   public static final int QS_ALLINPUT = 0x04FF;
   public static final int QS_ALLPOSTMESSAGE = 0x0100;
   public static final int QS_HOTKEY = 0x0080;
   public static final int QS_INPUT = 0x407;
   public static final int QS_KEY = 0x0001;
   public static final int QS_MOUSE = 0x0006;
   public static final int QS_MOUSEBUTTON = 0x0004;
   public static final int QS_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0002;
   public static final int QS_PAINT = 0x0020;
   public static final int QS_POSTMESSAGE = 0x0008;
   public static final int QS_RAWINPUT = 0x0400;
   public static final int QS_SENDMESSAGE = 0x0040;
   public static final int QS_TIMER = 0x0010;


   public static final int INFINITE =    0xFFFFFFFF;


   /*
   DWORD WINAPI MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(
   __in  DWORD nCount,
   __in  const HANDLE *pHandles,
   __in  BOOL bWaitAll,
   __in  DWORD dwMilliseconds,
   __in  DWORD dwWakeMask
   );*/


   int MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(int nCount, Pointer pHandles, boolean bWaitAll, int dwMilliSeconds, int dwWakeMask);


   /* fsModifiers vaues */
   public static final int MOD_ALT = 0x0001;
   public static final int MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
   public static final int MOD_NOREPEAT = 0x4000;
   public static final int MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004;
   public static final int MOD_WIN = 0x0008;


   /* BOOL WINAPI RegisterHotKey(
   __in_opt  HWND hWnd,
   __in      int id,
   __in      UINT fsModifiers,
   __in      UINT vk
   );
   */
   boolean RegisterHotKey(Pointer hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
   }
   ```
3. Just check out the following pages to get a clear idea of how things work under the hood:

h**p://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx

h**p://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242%28VS.85%29.aspx

1. Check this page to see what are the key constants you can register a callback for

h**p://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

1. Create a test program like this:

```
User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
boolean res = user32.RegisterHotKey(Pointer.NULL, 9999, User32.MOD_ALT | User32.MOD_CONTROL, WINUSER.VK_LEFT);
if(!res)
  System.out.println("Couldn't register hotkey");

System.out.println("Starting and waiting");
user32.MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, Pointer.NULL, true, User32.INFINITE, User32.QS_HOTKEY);
System.out.println("Ending");
```

User32.INFINITE is an undocumented constant with value 0xFFFFFFFF

Sorry about the http links renamed into h**p :) Stackoverflow rules
Stefano

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do this using `setVisible(false)` method.
Window will be there but user will not able to see it.